# How can the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality be derived only from the axioms of inner product space and the definition of norm of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I know alternate ways to derive it, however the book 'Advanced Engineering Mathematics' by Erwin Kreyszig, says that it can be derived from the following axioms and definition. I am curious to know how. I am attaching the screenshots of the pages which say so.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can change PDF pages to images if you really wish to post them as such.

Comment: I shall definitely be doing that henceforth. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $r \in \Bbb R$, we have 
$$
\| (a + rb) \| \ge 0$$ by axiom 3. 
Using the other axioms to expand this out:

\begin{align}
0 &\le \|(a + rb) \|^2 \\
0 &\le (a + rb) \cdot (a + rb) & \text{definition}\\
0 &\le a  \cdot (a+rb) +  r(b \cdot (a+rb)) & \text{Axiom I}\\
0 &\le (a+rb)  \cdot a +  r((a+rb) \cdot b) & \text{Axiom II, twice}\\
0 &\le a \cdot a +r(b  \cdot a) +  r((a+rb) \cdot b) & \text{Axiom I, on left-hand piece}\\
0 &\le a \cdot a +r(b  \cdot a) +  r(a \cdot b + r(b \cdot b))) & \text{Axiom I, on right-hand piece}\\
0 &\le a \cdot a +r(a  \cdot b) +  r(a \cdot b + r(b \cdot b))) & \text{Axiom II}\\
0 &\le a \cdot a +2r(a  \cdot b) +  r^2(b \cdot b) & \text{Distributive and associative}\\
&& \text{
and commutative laws for real-number addition}\\
0 &\le r^2 b \cdot b + 2r a \cdot b +  a \cdot a &\text{more of that}
\end{align}
The right hand side is a quadratic in $r$: $Ar^2 + Br + C$,where $A = b \cdot b$, $B = 2 a \cdot b$ and $C = a \cdot a$. And it's a quadratic whose values are always nonnegative, so it has at most one real root. That means that the discriminant, $B^2 - 4AC$, must be non-positive, i.e. 
\begin{align}
0 &\ge B^2 - 4AC \\
0 &\ge 4 (a \cdot b)^2 - 4 (a \cdot a) (b \cdot b)\\
 4 (a \cdot a) (b \cdot b) &\ge 4 (a \cdot b)^2 \\
(a \cdot a) (b \cdot b) &\ge  (a \cdot b)^2\\ 
\|a\|^2 \|b\|^2 &\ge  (a \cdot b)^2 \\
\|a\|~ \|b\| &\ge | a \cdot b |
\end{align}

And we're done.

Comment: Is it necessary to use a scalar variable 'r' to derive the inequality?

Comment: I doubt it, but it's the nicest proof I've seen, and uses almost everything from high-school algebra to prove something pretty darned cool, so that's the proof I gave.

Comment: I am sure that there is no way to establish this inequality without using the quadratic discriminant or using complex variables. Is there anyway we could find the original paper of the trio Cauchy/Schwarz/Bunyakovsky that derived this inequality?